# How to tag a question that has no plausible tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just tagged [uses for state machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255797/uses-for-state-machines) with 'terrible-question' and voted to close it. This can't be good, but what else is there to do?

Comment: Not tag it with that crap, for sure.  No offense, but meta-tags aren't allowed, and that's an obvious one.

Answer (score 11):

Why did it need to be retagged at all?

I mean, the original tags weren't *great*, but surely just voting to close is sufficient. You didn't make anything better with your retagging and arguably made it worse by replacing half-way/kinda/sorta/if-you-squint usable tags with a meta tag.

<s>I rolled back your edit.</s> At least the [statemachine](/questions/tagged/statemachine) tag still applies, so I put that one back.

The question itself seems kinda useful, too, even if not exactly stellar. I like the accepted answer, at any rate.

---

*In general*... it's incredibly rare for a question to not have any useful tags at all. When that happens, it's a safe bet that the question should be closed and deleted. In that case, there's not much point to retagging. Otherwise, there's gotta be *something* that could be come a relevant, useful tag even if one doesn't already exist on the site.

Comment: We are constantly told that the first step to removal of a meta-tag is to remove it from all existing questions. Since this question had only meta tags, I felt stumped.

Comment: p.s. no objection to the rollback. I was obviously overly grumpy in seeing statemachine as meta.

Comment: @Rosinante I might be missing something, but [statemachine] doesn't seem like a meta tag. The other two... yeah, they're pretty useless. :)

Comment: It might not be important to close old items that have useful content but which wouldn't pass current muster. On the other hand, the late answer queue tends to highlight their status a somewhat broken windows.

Comment: @Rosinante Yeah, I don't feel strongly enough about closure one way or another here. Maybe there's an edit that could be made to make the question stronger, but my attention is divided right now. I'd likely oppose *deleting* this question, though.

Comment: @Rosinante: How is "state-machines" a metatag?

Comment: It's totally not a meta tag.  It has a concrete meaning and can pretty much stand alone.

Comment: [Yeah, I think we already established that \[statemachine\] is a fine tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157657/how-to-tag-a-question-that-has-no-plausible-tags#comment455368_157658). :)